# Using gensim Scipy2Corpus without materializing sparse matrix in memory

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, gensim

I have three NumPy arrays saved to disk in `.npy` format, together totaling about 40 GB (representing text count data from a very large document set). The three arrays represent the `data`, `indices`, and `indptr` attributes of a [`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csc_matrix.html) sparse matrix.

I want to use distributed gensim LsiModel on this data, specifically with the [`gensim.matutils.Scipy2Corpus`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/matutils.html#gensim.matutils.Scipy2Corpus) function to provide the corpus iterator from the underlying sparse matrix.

However, I do not want to materialize the whole matrix in memory. Instead, how can I tell gensim about the underlying disk data and have gensim stream from disk into the csc matrix as needed to distribute chunks to the worker processes? If I understand correctly, this is what `Scipy2Corpus` and the [distributed LsiModel examples](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/dist_lsi.html) claim to do, but instead they require materializing the arrays into a csc matrix ahead of time.

I have tried loading each of the underlying arrays with `mmap_mode='r'`, but the function that constructs the materialized csc matrix, `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` will pull all of the data in regardless.

Comment: How well do you understand the `csr` format?  Describe what this streaming is supposed to do.  Send the array row by row (or by column)?  Or send 2d blocks.

Comment: The underlying data is in csc format, not csr. Each of the columns is a term, and the rows (which are very sparse term count vectors) correspond to documents. [Gensim does the conversion to csr](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/matutils.py#L167) and thus expects csc input. The streaming effect is to provide chunks of rows without needing to materialize the whole sparse matrix object.

Comment: What you need to do is construct some sparse matrices, and perform various conversions (to csc etc), indexing (1 or more rows or columns) and keep track of the `data`, `indices` and `indptr` attributes.  I'd check their `id` and their data pointer (`.__array_interface__['data']`).  The idea is to track when it is making a copy, and when it's just a view.  A view has a chance of using the `mmap`, a copy almost certainly will load the whole thing.

Comment: It's not about views vs. copies. Loading with `mmap_mode` set is a standard option for `numpy.load`. If you load and work with the separate underlying arrays individually, then you only pull data from them on-demand when using mmap reading mode. This is why the project saves the underlying `data`, `indices`, and `indptr` attributes separately instead of using some built-in sparse matrix serialization in scipy. The problem is that the gensim interface appears to suggest it will stream data from disk-backed arrays, but actually requires the whole sparse matrix to be loaded .

Comment: I'm talking about the views v copies of those underlying arrays.  `A[0,:]` is a view of a dense array.  But if `A` is sparse, that new matrix is not a view, and none of its attributes are views.  If you want several rows it actually performs matrix multiplication with 'mask' matrix.  I have fair idea of what `scipy.sparse` does; I know nothing about `gensim`.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. In order to create at all the object you call `A` , it would require loading in ~ 40GB memory. For instance, with the constructor `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix` applied to a tuple of values resulting from `numpy.load("...", mmap_mode="r")` on each of the `data`, `indices`, and `indptr` underlying files. That object is what the gensim interface accepts (and then creates a simple iterator on top of), but actually loading it into memory is not tractable. With some of the other corpus data structures that gensim works with, it appears possible to stream without loading.

Comment: Maybe I"m just confirming what you claimed at the start, that a `csr` matrix made from `memmap` arrays will use `ndarray` copies as attributes, not the originals.  So streaming without full loads will have to work with those `mmap` arrays directly, without any `scipy.sparse` intermediary.

Comment: That is what I've been working on in the meantime. I'm trying to read all the places in the gensim code that interact with the result of the call to `Scipy2Corpus` and treat it like an iterator. If I can make my own class that wraps the three data files but exposes the same interface for iterating and any other attributes, like `__len__`, that gensim assumes are available, then maybe I can sneak my own thing in as a gensim corpus and by "iterating" it will lazily read from the files. But without commentary from others who are knowledgeable about what gensim is doing, it's very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I made a sparse matrix:

```
In [207]: A=sparse.random(100,100,.1,'csr')
In [208]: A
Out[208]: 
<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1000 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Made copies of its attributes, and saved them

```
In [209]: D,I,J = A.data.copy(),A.indptr.copy(),A.indices.copy()
In [236]: np.save('sparse_d',D)
In [237]: np.save('sparse_I',I)
In [238]: np.save('sparse_J',J)
```

If I reload them as `mmap`, I can make a new matrix:

```
In [240]: D1=np.load('sparse_d.npy', mmap_mode='r')
In [241]: I1=np.load('sparse_I.npy', mmap_mode='r')
In [242]: J1=np.load('sparse_J.npy', mmap_mode='r')
In [243]: Amm=sparse.csr_matrix((D1,J1,I1),A.shape)
```

But the attributes of this new array are in memory copies of the files:

```
In [246]: type(D1)
Out[246]: numpy.core.memmap.memmap
In [247]: type(Amm.data)
Out[247]: numpy.ndarray
```

So a sparse matrix made from `mmap` arrays loads all the data (as claimed in the original post).

```
In [252]: A.indptr
Out[252]: 
array([   0,   10,   20,   29,   36,   46,   60,   66,   74,   85,   93,
        104,  117,  128,  139,  147,  156,  165,  172,  188,  201,  211, ...
```

I can get a slice of `A` with

```
In [254]: A37=A[3:7,:]
In [255]: A37
Out[255]: 
<4x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 37 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

This is a copy of `A`, not a view (as it would have been for a dense array).

The relevant `indptr` values for these rows is

```
In [256]: I1[3:8]
Out[256]: memmap([29, 36, 46, 60, 66])
```

66-29 is 37, the number of nonzero values in `A37`.

I could make a sparse matrix from slices of the `mmap` arrays:

```
In [259]: Amm37=sparse.csr_matrix((D1[29:66],J1[29:66],I1[3:8]-I1[3]), shape=(4, 100))
In [260]: Amm37
Out[260]: 
<4x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 37 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [261]: np.allclose(A37.A, Amm37.A)
Out[261]: True
```

While the attributes of `Amm37` are in memory, the `D1` and `J1` inputs to the function are `mmap` slices:

```
In [262]: D1[29:66]
Out[262]: 
memmap([ 0.08874032,  0.18952295,  0.43034343,  0.83725733,  0.61073925,
        0.9178207 ,  0.03644072,  0.32206696,  0.90945298,  0.20585155,
        .... 0.43905333])
In [263]: I1[3:8]-I1[3]
Out[263]: array([ 0,  7, 17, 31, 37])
```

So yes, I can recreate a row slice of the original `A` from the saved attributes, without loading whole the mmap arrays.  All I need is selected slices from the 3 arrays.  Similarly I could select columns from a `csc` format array.

But it would be very difficult to pull a column from `csr` attributes without loading them entirely.  The desired `data` and `indices` values will be scattered through out the stored arrays.  Converting `csr` attributes to `csc` requires creating the full `csr` matrix and using its `tocsc()` method.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that the data format I start off with is in csc format, not csr, even though the relevant iteration dimension is the rows (the documents). The csc matrix exists from some different application where quickly traversing columns (terms) is required. But to apply LSA to improve performance in the same application, it would be required to start with the mmap files that define the csc matrix and iterate *row-wise* over it, despite the fact that it's csc.